# how to implement GridGain GridSegmentationResolver

Tags: gridgain

I am trying to add GridSegmentationResolver to the GridConfig. But it seems it is not being invoked. Look around in the source code and I found that the open source GridSegmentationProcessor is a mock implementation which always return true.

So the question is how to add our own Segmentation handling in the open source version of GridGain? Or it requires enterprise version?

Answer (score 0):

Network segmentation handling is part of GridGain enterprise edition only. It is not possible to add segmentation handling in open source edition.